# How to create a copy of exisiting docker image

Tags: ubuntu, docker, debian, dockerfile

I've been trying to use docker for a while, these are docker images I've downloaded.

```
debian                 latest    8c00acfb0175        2 weeks ago         125.2 MB
sameersbn/postgresql   latest    1da0f78d061e        3 weeks ago         231.6 MB
ubuntu                 latest    91e54dfb1179        5 weeks ago         188.4 MB
docker/whalesay        latest    fb434121fc77        4 months ago        247 MB
sameersbn/postgresql   9.4       271ad7e099d3        7 months ago        228.2 MB
```

How can I've base image for debian or ubuntu locally, and build some testing images on top of them and not disturb base images, so that I don't have to download base docker images again, and I can use fresh downloaded images multiple time ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply write a Dockerfile starting with:

```
FROM debian:latest
...
```

(using the [`FROM` directive](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#from))

That will create a local image based on debian, and since debian is already downloaded, it won't be downloaded again.

Note: it is best to avoid the "latest" tag: see "[Docker: The latest Confusion](http://container-solutions.com/docker-latest-confusion/)" by Stack Overflow contributor [Adrian Mouat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4332/adrian-mouat).
Using actual labels is more precise:

```
docker pull debian:7.8
docker pull debian:wheezy
```

> If wanted to do something in ubuntu is there a way when: I just execute command `docker copy "image_name"` and then do whatever I want to (run image, clone some git repo, install some packages, test it) , and then just delete it `docker rmi "image_name"` (when I'm done with image) .

Yes: you can `docker run --it <image> bash` (for images which includes `bash`), and exit that bash: your container will be exited: you can then `docker commit <containerrid> newimage`, and you will get a copy of the original image.

Comment: Thank you for answer, it does what I need. Just little question, by any chance is there any command like 'docker copy ' image-name' and we can start working on that image ?

Comment: @proton1h1 by "start working", do you mean run it? Or adding new directive (in which case, that is what the Dockerfile is for)

Comment: Yup, Dockerfile will do what I wanted, but just in case: 

If wanted to do something in ubuntu is there a way when: 
I just execute command `docker copy "image_name"` and then do whatever I want to(run image, clone some git repo, installl some packages, test it) , and then just delete it `docker rmi "image_name"` (when I'm done with image) .

Dockerfile will do the same for me and it's nice way, but are there any such command ?

Comment: There is no command like "docker copy" on image which could allow copy one image to other as of now. You could use docker save and export feature which is helpful when you want to use the saved docker image in a different Docker host. Other way is to wrap the "Dockefile" logic ( for example example "FROM ubuntu:14.04") in shell script which will build the copy of the base image.

Comment: @proton1h1 you can try and use docker commit: see my edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

The images what you listed using the command "docker images" can be re-used. Here are 2 ways how you can extend or re-use an base image without downloading it again.

#### 1. Using Dockerfile, [link](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/)

In Dockerfile you can put the Instruction "FROM REPOSITORY_NAME:TAG_NAME" as first line to re-use already downloaded base image

```
FROM REPOSITORY_NAME:TAG_NAME
```

In "docker images" command output, 1st column gives REPOSITORY name and 2nd column give TAG name.

You can further add more instructions in Dockerfile and build it.

#### 2. Using Docker commit feature ( not as easy as Dockerfile approach)

a. Start the container from the base image

b. Login to the container, make the changes to the container like install additional rpms etc if required.

c. commit the results for new image created on base image.

```
docker commit -m "installed wireshark" -a "admin" "container-id" "your_repository_name"/"user_name":"New_TAG"
```

d. Run "docker images" command, you can see the new image (which is prepared on top of existing, already downloaded image)